# How to deploy war file in Weblogic using command line?

Tags: deployment, weblogic, devops

java weblogic.Deployer -adminurl http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:7001 -username "username" -password "password" -targets AdminServer -noexit -deploy -name my.war -source my.war

when I'm trying to deploy using this I'm getting error like

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to load class org.hibernate.HibernateException
```

Comment: your command is correct but your application misses hibernate lib dependency.

Comment: how to rectify that? when I'm using the GUI I'm able to deploy that war file using the console.

Comment: is your application deployed and started when using the admin console ?

Comment: started the weblogic server as admin  ...but unable to deploy into that server .

Comment: so your application is not deployable because the hibernate lib is missing. You have to include the requested lib in the war file (WEB-INF/lib for instance)